# Login to openvpn web GUI after change IP

Tags: security, openvpn, encryption

My provider just changed my IP address. How can I login to my web GUI with my new IP address?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change it in "server.conf"

```
server new_ip_addr 255.255.255.0
```

After that restart the server:

```
/etc/init.d/openvpn restart server
```

Comment: ok this weird. There is no openvpn directory in `/etc` but openvpn_as is available in `/usr/local/`. I try to remove openvpn with `apt-get --purge remove openvpn` but had this error `Package 'openvpn' is not installed, so not removed` I could not find `server.conf`

Comment: Ok so run and paste results of this command : "dpkg --get-selections | grep -i vpn"

Comment: I actually install `openvpn access server`. After reconfigure using the steps from here`http://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/docs/91-how-to-access-server/general/124-how-to-activate-your-license-key.html` I now can login to my vpn server but no internet access. Thanks for trying to help.